# CSS hovering issue

Tags: css

Please refer this fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/shrikanth/79AfQ/

After hovering header(h2), div element(popup) is displayed , which is as per design.
However I can't navigate to new div.(new div gets disappear soon after moving out h2 element)

Is there any fix for this , so that user can click on headrer then can click on contact of another div element?

HTML

```
<h2>What is CSS?</h2>
<div id="popup">
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h2 {
    position:relative;
    top:22px;
    left:44px;
    width: 170px;
    height:33px;
    text-align:center;
}
#popup {
    width: 240px;
    background: #727272;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    top:15px;
    left:44px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    display:none;
}
h2:hover+ #popup {
    display:inline-block;
}
h2:hover {
    background-color:green;
}
#popup:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #727272 transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 92px;
}
```

Comment: If you want to click instead of hover then Javascript / JQuery will be required.

Comment: Thanks , Paulie, yes  it can be done using jquery . But here I'm looking for CSS perspective...

Comment: Then you're out of luck...if you want a **click**, you have to use JS.

Comment: something http://jsfiddle.net/79AfQ/1/ like this can be done but HTML markup still to be improved. This markup is not so semantic

Comment: yes...looks good. Please can you please elaborate what exactly you have done here?  I could see changes made on  div popup positioning (top:-6px; left:-25px;).  Please help  so that I can make use of this in future. Thanks a lot

Comment: Pravin made the popup div a **child** of the heading, not a sibling as in your original post. When you hover the heading, the popup shows (making the header expand). Then when you hover the popup, you are still in the header (as it's the parent). Hope you understand. @PravinVaichal: in HTML5 it is allowed to use div's, even in inline elements (suchs a `p` or `a`). I however don't like it either...

Comment: @shrikanth I have changed markup and kept popup div inside H2 so that hover on H2 will remain as it is when you hover on popup div as well - LinkinTED yea I dont like either as well hence not posted as answer. just as in case required as quick fix :)

Comment: Thank you..  Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the hover pseudo-selector rule to include the #popup element, too (assuming your goal is just to be able to click the contact link in the #popup)

```
h2:hover+ #popup, #popup:hover{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to use this approach, I suggest adding padding to the h2 element to allow your mouse to leave it without immediately deactivating the hover state, or wrapping it with a larger, invisible element.

Comment: Very precise mouse movement is required to ensure that the hover doesn't come off the `h2`.

Comment: @Paulie_D- The pop-up will hide as soon as the hover comes off. You can give top bottom padding to your h2, if you don't mind the extra green color.

Comment: Simple and effective solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add the #popup inside the h2 and absolutely position it.
This way, when you're hovering over the popup, you'll be hovering over the h2 as well.
One thing to note here is not to leave any spaces between h2 and the popup, like ReeceJHayward suggested.

```
<h2>What is CSS?
<div id="popup">
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
</h2>
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/79AfQ/7/